# Header collides with text

Tags: scrpage2

My headline collides with my text / chapters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot,  ngerman]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings 
\clearscrplain 
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{text1} 
\ohead{text2}
\chead{text3} 
\setheadsepline{0.4pt} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setstretch{1.4}
\section{Section1}
\end{document}
```

If I use

```
\setlength{\headsep}{0.45in}
```

The problem ist fixed however my the top margin before any content, in this case the header is too much for my taste.

Comment: Remove the package fullpage. i.e.  `%\usepackage{fullpage}`

Comment: @Fran Thanks! With this I don't even need the  `\setlength{\headsep}{0.45in}` command. @cfr The 0.4pt are for the thickness of the separation line beneath the header. The 0.45in were for the top margin, the values and units were meant that way.

Comment: @idkfa Sorry. I misread it. Serves me right for trying to do too many things at once! You should ask Fran to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [fullpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) package without options does not allow enough space for the header, because is equivalent to use:

```
\usepackage[in,empty]{fullpage}
```

That is, a margin of one inch with space for neither headers nor footers. If you want a little margins with  headers, use:

```
\usepackage[cm,headings]{fullpage}
```

> [image: MWE]

In other case, do not use this package. The [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package is a more flexible interface to customize the page layout. Note that in KOMA-script documents you can also  use the `DIV=<value>` option for the document class for this purpose.